# rock paper sicssors game computer says null

Tags: java

So i have made a small program for the game rok paper scissors and when i play the computer says idk aka the return value and no mater what it always says idk/null: such as if i enter in "rock" it says 
" you picked rock
cpu choose idk
you win
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)"

```
package rpc;

import static java.lang.System.console;
import java.util.*;


public class Rpc {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );

        String choice = scan.nextLine();

        if (isValid(choice)) {
            int aIChoice = (int)(Math.random() + 3);
            int personChoice = getVal(choice);
            //0=rock 1=paper 2=scissors
            System.out.println("you picked " + choice);
            System.out.println("cpu choose " + getAIChoice(aIChoice));
            System.out.println("you " + didPersonWin(personChoice, aIChoice));
        } else {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid selection");
        }
    }
    public static String getAIChoice(int x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            return "rock";

        }
        if (x == 1) {
            return "paper";

        }
        if (x == 2) {
            return "sicssors";

        }
        return "idk";
    }

    public static String didPersonWin(int pChoice, int ComputerChoice) {
        if (pChoice == 0) {
            if (ComputerChoice != 1) {
                if (ComputerChoice != 0) {
                    return "win";
                }
                return "tie";
            }
            return "loose";
        }
        if (pChoice == 1) {
            if (ComputerChoice != 2) {
                if (ComputerChoice != 1) {
                    return "win";
                }
                return "tie";
            }
            return "loose";
        }
        if (pChoice == 2) {
            if (ComputerChoice != 0) {
                if (ComputerChoice != 2) {
                    return "win";
                }
                return "tie";
            }
            return "loose";
        }
        return "idk";
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String string) {
        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
    public static int getVal(String string) {
        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have all of your statements checking for `rock`.

Comment: Suggest you look at the Javadoc for [Math.random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29). Also look at the line where you are setting `aiChoice`. Pretend you are the computer. What values, of what data type, can `Math.random()` have? Now what values, of what data type, can `Math.random() + 3` have? Now what values, of what data type, can you get if you cast that to `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this line :

```
  int aIChoice = (int)(Math.random()+3);
```

With this one :

```
  int aIChoice = (int)(Math.random()*3);
```

The first one will always return `3` and so `idk` in your `getAIChoice` method.